# WordPress Database Charset/Collate

Tags: database, encoding

Is there an easy way of getting the charset and collation of the DB tables in WordPress without resorting to SQL queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `$wpdb->charset` and `$wpdb->collate`. I am not sure if or when one of these values might be empty, so it is better to prepare for empty values …

From my DB class:

```
/**
 * Get table charset and collation.
 *
 * @since  2012.10.22
 * @return string
 */
protected static function get_wp_charset_collate() {

    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = '';

    if ( ! empty ( $wpdb->charset ) )
        $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";

    if ( ! empty ( $wpdb->collate ) )
        $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";

    return $charset_collate;
}
```

Used to create a table like this:

```
    global $wpdb;

    // encoding
    $charset_collate = self::get_wp_charset_collate();
    $table           = self::get_table_name();

    // the user could have just deleted the plugin without running the clean up.
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        ID bigint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        event_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        event_group tinytext,
        event_title text,
        PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
    ) $charset_collate;";


    // make dbDelta() available
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

    dbDelta( $sql );
```

Related: [Problem with blog charset UTF-7](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77108/if-a-hacker-changed-the-blog-charset-to-utf-7-does-that-make-wordpress-vulnerabl/77112#77112)

Answer (score 1):

The file `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php` includes `wp-admin/includes/schema.php`. This at the top declare as global ([see source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L11)):

```
// Declare these as global in case schema.php is included from a function.
 global $wpdb, $wp_queries, $charset_collate;
...
$charset_collate = '';

if ( ! empty( $wpdb->charset ) )
    $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";
if ( ! empty( $wpdb->collate ) )
    $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";
```

So you can follow @Toscho's answer and check `$wpdb`. Or, using Toscho's example:

```
global $wpdb, $charset_collate;
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    ID bigint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    event_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    event_group tinytext,
    event_title text,
    PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
) $charset_collate;";

dbDelta( $sql );
```

Note the `IF NOT EXISTS` is not required [as `dbDelta()` handles this](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L1484).