# If a hacker changed the blog_charset to UTF-7 does that make WordPress vulnerable to further attacks?

Tags: security, encoding, hacked, characters

I had a client who got hacked recently and I noticed that there were weird characters appearing on her site, like Â and Æ. It turns out that the hackers changed the blog_charset to UTF-7 in the `wp_options` table in the database. I set it back to UTF-8, but I was wondering if during the time it was set to UTF-7, could that create any security vulnerabilities?

I did some searching and discovered there used to be a [WordPress UTF-7 vulnerability that was fixed in version 2.0.6](http://www.securiteam.com/exploits/5XP072AKAQ.html).  We're running the most recent version of WordPress, so they couldn't have used that exploit, but are there any other exploits related to UTF-7? Really, is there any reason the hackers would change the blog_charset other than to be a pain? I've been trying to determine how they got in and I'm wondering if this is connected somehow.

Answer (score 22):

`<` and `>` are encoded as `+ADw-` and `+AD4-` in [UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7). Now imagine the following:

1. Someone sends `+ADw-script+AD4-alert(+ACI-Hello+ACI-)+ADw-/script+AD4-` as comment text. It will pass all sanitation unescaped.
2. The database expects and treats all incoming data as UTF-8. Since all UTF-7 streams are valid UTF-8 too, this will never result in a SQL error, and `mysql_real_escape` or `htmlspecialchars` will not touch it.
3. WordPress sends a header `text/html;charset=utf-7`.
4. WordPress displays the comment, expecting escaped data. But since this is treated as UTF-7 by the browser the JavaScript will be executed.

So, yes, it is a security problem.

UTF-7 is not supported by all browsers, most will render the text as Windows-1252 (or whatever is the default encoding on their OS) or as UTF-8. 
The main problem is: escaping will not work anymore.

---

Just changing the encoding value back is not a solution. A regular visitor can never change it, so you *have* to find the open door.

Comment: Thanks! I'll cross my fingers that fixing that database entry has closed the security hole.

Comment: Don't worry, I'd already taken several actions to close security holes. I just couldn't figure out how they were still getting in. Nothing seems to have been hacked in the last few days, so hopefully changing the encoding back to UTF-8 was the final step in closing all the holes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it might be needed (re-converting all the encodings of your tables):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8